# Can't connect to wireless routers and settings page - connection refused

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

1st router.

I can't connect to my wireless router setting page at `192.168.1.1`. in chrome it says `"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"`. I didn't have this problem before. this happens to another router too. I'm using a wireless network adapter for wireless connection. I changed my MAC address, used this command: `NETSH WINSOCK RESET` , restarted PC, refreshed everything using IE settings.

2nd router

There is another router for my friend that gave me it's password and I used to connect to it successfully but now i can't. I tried everything i could but none of them worked. I'm using Windows 8.1 and the error i get when trying to connect to that router is this: "Can't connect to this network". on this network my friend set up a QOS and set a static Internal IP for my MAC address. I don't know what's wrong with my computer. I also haven't Installed any Windows updates recently.

**IP config Output**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain.name

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TP-link Wireless adapter 802.11b/g   54Mbps
USB 2.0 Network Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-C0-BA-3A-4C-5E
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1961:9d21:bd7c:fcf3%29(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, July 1, 2015 5:02:26 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, July 2, 2015 5:02:25 PM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 302039242
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-AC-AF-BC-54-42-49-F6-CF-F9

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                   8.8.4.4
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-D0-2B-C5-2D-6F
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9590:b3e4:e8fb:d1f6%8(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 175427627
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-AC-AF-BC-54-42-49-F6-CF-F9

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Kerio Virtual Network:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Kerio Virtual Network Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 44-45-53-54-4F-53
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::14d0:7d29:f86a:4124%14(Preferred)
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.65.36(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 356795731
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-AC-AF-BC-54-42-49-F6-CF-F9

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet
1
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7128:f9d7:a5bb:72dd%31(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.147.1(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 486559830
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-AC-AF-BC-54-42-49-F6-CF- F9

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c83e:7ac0:4762:fb52%32(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 838881366
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-AC-AF-BC-54-42-49-F6-CF-F9

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{6C49020A-98D2-48B0-984D-65C147047475}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{3430FAAF-97F3-410C-97B4-BA1AAFCE1FC3}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

 Tunnel adapter isatap.{610BCE9C-8DD1-4874-8A4C-2AED8A2CC2AE}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.domain.name:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{41B0142F-60AE-48D7-9374-8A164EA54798}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: try connecting over ethernet. Some routers don't allow logging to the setup over wifi.

Comment: You're right, but unfortunately that's not an option for my situation. the weird thing is that when i enter the router public IP on the browser i can log into the settings page.

Comment: That's a security issue, for sure.

Comment: I'm confused: the first sentence of your question says you can't connect to your router settings page, while your last comment says you can. So what _is_ the problem?

Comment: @AFH 1st and 2nd questions refer to 2 different routers. In 1st question, I can only connect to my router settings page through Internet. in 2nd question, I can't connect to the router itself, let alone accessing its settings page.

Comment: Could you add to your question the IP settings for your WiFi interface, extracted from the `ipconfig /all` output?

Comment: @AFH Yes i added them

Comment: That all looks in order unfortunately, so we have to look elsewhere. Did you power the router off and on? Have you tried clearing the browser cache, as well as saved forms and passwords? You can make sure no saved settings are confusing matters by trying a different browser, such as one of those on [Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/). Have you any other machines on the network? Do they have the same problem?

Comment: @AFH Yes I tried on different machines, Virtual machines and even my phone. In Windows it just says it can't connect to that network, doesn't say that the password is incorrect or anything. the router is not in my place so It might have gotten turned off and on. this is really weird for me.

Comment: If you can get into the settings from the internet, you should be able to restart it from there, provided any other users don't mind. Also confirm that the Wifi password is what your machine thinks it is.

Comment: @AFH Yes it's a good idea for 1st question, but for the 2nd one the problem was wireless MAC filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st.

the problem is OS related. It's only my computer that refuses to connect to the router settings, other computers can successfully connect to `192.168.1.1`.

2nd.

I found what the problem was, the way router was responding to my connection request even with different devices was weird so that's how i found it. It was about Wireless MAC filtering which gives the router the ability to allow only wireless devices with specific MAC address to connect to it. my friend also confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your VMware Network Adapter is Disabled or not.
It may use the dhcp ip-address having range 192.168.0.0/24.
Disable it.